# Problem with Cyrillic characters when knitting .rmd files to pdf with tinytex

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

I have a problem whenever I have a .rmd file with Cyrillic characters in it and I try to knit it to a pdf, e.g.:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document: default
---

Това е тест
```

When I press 'knit' I get the output file `report.pdf`, but the Cyrillic characters are not in there, instead there are several question-mark-looking characters in an all-white font:

[image]

If I copy paste the white characters they look like this:

```
���� � ����
```

Now this seem to be some issue with missing fonts maybe, but I don't know how and what to install with tinytex. Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: I am using `tinytex 2021.08` and this is my `sessionInfo`:

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=bg_BG.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=bg_BG.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=bg_BG.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=bg_BG.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] processx_3.5.3  compiler_4.2.1  R6_2.5.1        fastmap_1.1.0   cli_3.3.0       htmltools_0.5.2
 [7] tools_4.2.1     yaml_2.3.5      rmarkdown_2.14  knitr_1.39      callr_3.7.0     xfun_0.31      
[13] digest_0.6.29   ps_1.7.0        rlang_1.0.2     evaluate_0.15
```